# My screen displays weird things

Tags: hdmi, screen, pi-zero-w

I have a problem with my raspberry pi zero. My HDMI screen shows weird things (see below). Other screens work fine it is only this one. I can move my mouse fine. Can I solve this issue or do I have to send it back?
I appreciate your help.

EDIT:  I have tried using different sources and HDMI cables.I tried rotating the output of the pi and set the signal strenght up in the config.txt file. I unplugged and plugged the ribbon cable on the back of the screen.

[image: The screen]

Comment: "I've tried some things but they didn't help." — It'd be great if you could share what you did, and how it didn't work; it might help us with debugging the problem more easily. You can just [edit] what you tried in, which will bump your question for more attention.